# what could I do with HelloWorld-debug.apk file?

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I compiled successful project **HTML5** to **Android** by Cordova, it produced some files as `HelloWorld-debug.apk`, `HelloWorld-debug-unaligned.apk` ...

Really I don't know meaning of debug, unaligned, I want upload file `apk` to **Android** market, this files met enough requirements of Google?

Comment: Have u added release key ??? and also share the steps it will help

Comment: Really I follow steps from Phonegap documentation, I don't know what key is, you can describe it?

Comment: yes, but I only use eclipse to create AVD, I built apk file from cmd cordova, I need some instructions to complete it (icon, key ...) which Google will approve it.

Comment: Try with eclipse its easy check this [out](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/build-android-application-package-file-apk-using-eclipse-ide/)

Answer (score 1):

the -debug apk is you app unsigned with debug info. It can be installed on your device. (need to allow installation of unknown apps)

If you want to have a release app you need to run

```
platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --release
```

(replace \ with / and remove .bat for unix based computers)

and then to sign the app :

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore pathtoyourkeystorefile.keystore platforms\android\bin\yourapp-release-unsigned.apk nameofthekeyinkeystore
```

replace `pathtoyourkeystorefile.keystore` with the path to your previously created keystore file, `yourapp` with the name of your app and `nameofthekeyinkeystore` with the name of your key in the keystore

and then your file will still be named -release-unsigned.apk so you can rename it to -release-signed.apk or just .apk and it will be ready to be uploaded to the store.

Comment: thanks, you're enthusiastic. I find a way to combine both, first of all, we generate resource by cordova, then we create new project in eclipse, choose feature "Android project from existing code". Thanks everyone.